# Accessing Custom Tool properties with polymorphism

Tags: c#, winforms

Somewhat new to C#. I'm going to try and explain my problem as best as I can.

I'm having a hard time getting at properties that I have made on a custom tool. I have many of these tools on my GUI so it's not as simple as just typing it out explicitly with the property. These controls are contained within a List and I want to be able to easily access their properties (which is part of their isolated and separate solution project). Here is my example of what I have so far:

```
List<Control> controlList = new List<Control>();
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    foreach (var item in controlList)
    {
       if (item.Enabled)
       {
           custom_control1.Code = "8917237";
           custom_control1.MacAddress = "000000000001";
       }
    }

 // do other stuff based on the above credentials

 }
```

I'd like to be able to do the following in my if statement:

```
   item.Code = .... // calculation
   item.MacAddress = .... // this will increment in hex depending on how many controls I have Enabled
```

so that each instance of 'item' has that custom control property that I can change with a for loop or something. Note: each control tool item would have a different MAC and code based upon a calculation.

I'm not sure how to implement this. I guess my main problem is I'm able to see the default list of properties (like Visible, Enable, etc...) but not my Custom properties. Doing something like: `controlList[0].Code` also does not help me, because of the same issue. I'm obviously misunderstanding something here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If I read your question correctly... simply add all the 'shared' properties and methods to an `interface`, let your controls `implement` the interface (perhaps with a possibly overridden abstract base class). Then in your controlList loop, cast your control to the interface type

Comment: When you say "custom tool", do you mean that you've created a subclass of Control?

Comment: @ChristopheD Thanks for the help. It sounds like you have understood my problem, however I am not at the level where I can understand it and then implement your answer procedure. If you have the time, is it possible to provide an example that I could learn from? I could then probably implement from that point of understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your custom properties directly in the list objects, the list needs to be a list of your custom class, not `Control`. So, instead of

```
List<Control> controlList = new List<Control>();
```

use

```
List<MyCustomClass> controlList = new List<MyCustomClass>();
```

Comment: This works!! I'm able to get at my custom properties with List<project.classname> Thank you.